# AWSでMFAを使用したルートユーザのログインを複数人で行うには？

Tags: aws, aws-iam

ルートユーザのMFAとしてスマホのGoogle認証を設定しています。
MFAを使用したルートユーザのログインを、私以外にもできるようにするにはどうすればよいでしょうか？私以外の管理者は遠く離れた場所で作業しています。

Answer (score 1):

[AWS アカウントのルートユーザー](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_root-user.html)では

> 強くお勧めしているのは、日常的なタスクには、それが管理者タスクであっても、ルートユーザーを使用しないことです。代わりに、最初の IAM ユーザーを作成するためにのみ、ルートユーザーを使用するというベストプラクティスに従います。その後、ルートユーザーの認証情報を安全な場所に保管し、それらを使用して少数のアカウントおよびサービス管理タスクのみを実行します。

と説明されています。基本的に**ルートユーザーを使用するべきではありません**。

その上で複数人が使用するのであれば、個人に紐づいてしまう仮想MFAデバイスではなくハードウェアMFAデバイスを用意するべきでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=137055&start=100&tstart=0
ここを見る限り、AWSに仮想MFA端末（スマホのGoogle認証等）を登録時に表示されるQRコードを画像として保存し、複数端末で読み込むしかなさそうです。
2013年に問題提議されてから２０２１年の年末時点まで、AWSは対応していないようです。

Answer (score 0):

認証とは「本人であることを確認するもの」なので、第三者がMFAを使ってログインすることなど通常は想定しません。
sayuriさんが記載されていることが全てです。
そもそもrootユーザを使うのをやめて、ちゃんとIAMユーザを発行してください。